# Strange behaviour of JavaScript in Chrome Developer Tool

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, v8

Recently, working with JavaScript in Developer Tool, I found strange feature. Chrome accepts any code between opening bracket with operator (plus, minus sign) and operator with closing brackets and executes it, like this:
[image]

I didn't find this behaviour in another browsers, just in Chrome.

Maybe it's a feature, but why and how it works, can it be problem with JavaScript engine?

Comment: I do like how you called it a feature and not a bug

Comment: I wrote a little article about it: https://medium.com/@asaskevich/how-does-chrome-executes-scripts-inside-developer-tool-59a5ea8f7de2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the way chrome evaluates your input:

```
with (typeof __commandLineAPI !== 'undefined' ? __commandLineAPI : { __proto__: null }) {
 // your code here...
}
```

So once your input is `}{`
it becomes

```
with (typeof __commandLineAPI !== 'undefined' ? __commandLineAPI : { __proto__: null }) {}{} // indefined
```

Next input `}-+{`
becomes

```
undefined -+ {} // NaN
```

And so on.

Comment: Note: the object is called `__commandLineAPI`, not `commandLineAPI`. Also worth noting that this object represents Chrome [Command Line API](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api).

Comment: @gxoptg sure, seems to be a result of how redactor has parsed my code ;)

Answer (score 5):

This happens because Chrome wraps the code you enter in the console in the following construction:

```
with (typeof __commandLineAPI !== 'undefined' ? __commandLineAPI : { __proto__: null }) {
  // Your code
}
```

So, when you enter something like `} 10 {`, the code evaluates to:

```
with (typeof __commandLineAPI !== 'undefined' ? __commandLineAPI : { __proto__: null }) {
  } 10 {
}
```

which is empty `with` block, a number, and empty structural block.

`__commandLineAPI` is the internal object that contains [Chrome Command Line API](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api).